# Retornar campo diferente do inserido na clausula GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
| id | payment_id | user_id | device | 
 ------------------------------------
  1  |     2     |     1   | active |
 ------------------------------------
  2  |     4     |     5   | not_active
 ------------------------------------
  3  |     8     |     1   | not_active 
------------------------------------
  4  |    10     |     5   | active |
 ------------------------------------
  5  |    12     |     1   | active
 ------------------------------------
  6  |    14     |     1   | active
------------------------------------
  7  |    16     |     3   | active |
 ------------------------------------
  8  |    18     |     7   | active
 ------------------------------------
  9  |    20     |     7   | active
 ------------------------------------
```

Eu gostaria de fazer um query que retorna o payment_id apenas dos usuários que tem mais do que 2 device igual a active.

Pensei nisso:

```
SELECT payment_id 
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(device) > 2
```

Nesse caso eu retornaria os payment_ids 2, 12 e 14 o user_id igual a 1.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query estava "quase pronta", faltou usar o `WHERE` para retornar apenas os registros com `device='active'`  e no `HAVING` contar mais de 2 ocorrências, mas isso não ia retornar o 2, 12 e 14, ia retornar também o 8.

Primeiro, é preciso fazer um query que retorne *"todos os user_id, que tenham mais de dois device='active'"*, que seria algo assim:

```
 select user_id
   from teste
  where device='active'
  group by user_id 
 having count(user_id) > 2;
```

Isso iria retornar o user_id=1. Mas nem todos os registros com o user_id=1 são active, para isso, vamos fazer uma outra query, que use essa anterior por base, e filtro somente `device='active'`:

```
 select payment_id 
   from teste
  where device='active'
    and user_id in (
     select user_id
       from teste
      where device='active'
      group by user_id 
     having count(user_id) > 2)
  and device='active';
```

Pode ver funcinando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58a17e/6

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda Ricardo